# Use of s3:PutBucketPolicy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying few things with aws s3 bucket policy and the documentation for put-bucket-policy says that the user should have PutBucketPolicy on the bucket **and** should be the owner.

I do not understand the use of PutBucketPolicy permission then.
Also is the bucket owner given a default PutBucketPolicy permission on his bucket?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTpolicy.html

Answer (score 1):

The confusion here, I suspect, is related to the fact that *users* don't own buckets.  The "owner" of a bucket is an individual AWS account.

You can't successfully grant `PutBucketPolicy` to any user in a different AWS account -- only your own account's user(s).

There's an illusion of circular logic here: How can I set a bucket policy... allowing myself to set the bucket policy... unless I am already able to set the bucket policy... which would make it unnecessary to set a bucket policy allowing me to set the bucket policy?

This is not as it seems: the problem is resolved by the fact that IAM *user* policies can grant a user permission to set the bucket policy, and the root account can do this by default -- which is why [you should not use your root account credentials routinely](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html): they are too privileged, if they fall into the wrong hands.